# No citations/bibliography processed/produced when using \include

Tags: biblatex, input, include

I use TextMate 2 to write my LaTeX documents. I've noticed that when I use `\include` to add chapters, my citations don't process, whereas when I use `\input`, they do. I would like my document to have page breaks at the chapters, thus I prefer to use `\include`. (The `\includeonly` command is also a very nice benefit.)

I compiled my document (cmd R) and noticed no `.bbl` was created. This is despite the fact that TextMate (with `latexmk` automatically runs LaTex and Biblatex multiple times for each compiling). I ran Biblatex independently.  A `.bbl` for the main document was created, but was apparently empty, as when I compiled the document again the citations in the document did not appear, and there was no bibliography. I changed one of the chapters to `\input` and compiled, and the citations were processed and a bibliography (for those citations in that chapter only) was produced.

Am I doing something wrong? Why doesn't bibliographic material get produced with `\include`?

If I can't create a bibliography using `\include`, what is the easiest way to create page breaks for chapters using `\input`? I assume it would be to put `\pagebreak` before each `\input` command.

Comment: In the normal documentclasses a `\chapter` always starts on a new page anyway, so you don't have to add anything.

Comment: maybe this can help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include

Answer (score 1):

The following exmaple shows, that `biblatex` in conjunction with biber has no limitations in that matter and can handle included files as well. The important thing to remember is: Run `biber` not `bibtex` on the `basename.bcf` which contains the information on what to cite of *all* included files.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
%a helper file
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-Duck.tex}
    \chapter{this is some duck chapter}
    \cite{companion}
    and \blindtext
\end{filecontents}
%another helper file
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-Peng.tex}
    \chapter{this is some penguin chapter}
    \cite{aristotle:physics}
    and \blindtext
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
test\cite{westfahl:space}
\include{\jobname-Peng}
\include{\jobname-Duck}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```